# calling external web site pages from my web site

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net web site built with .net 2.0 framework. we recently purchased a source code for the product that we would like to integrate into our web site. This purchased source code is written in asp.net 3.5. I can deploy this pruchased source code as a separate web site in our IIS box. Once I deploy this, can I call the pages in that web site from my web site? Both the websites will be under same domain. I think I can use Iframes to call external web pages but I am not sure if it is a good idea.

Please let me know what could be the best way to do this?

Thanks,
Sridhar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to run both code on the same asp.net version.

You can try yours to move it to 3.5, or the other to turn it to 2.0 and test it and may work, some times even they are on 3.5 they not use any functions that can not run also on 2.0

About using iframe. This is depend from what you going to show on it. In general you going to have many issues to solve. Also you can not run under the same site different asp.net versions, so you must split in 2 different sub-domains your sites.

So try to make the same versions first, and then if this fail see the rest scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, convert your .Net 2 App to 3.5 (or even 4 if your component will work with 4.0)
Otherwise what you face is a huge issue with GET/POST values form App1 to App2, Run a test server first to rough out any issues & than deploy your web app as ONE single application.

In the long run this will save you time.